# My first pop does not move up when they keyboard is open, it's on IOS side

Tags: ios

I have several type's of pop-up's and a one dialog component to open them according to name, but I have problem with the very first name of pop-up that shows-up on the screen, when I try to open it on IOS, keyboard is not moving the pop-up to the top, so it actually cover and I have to scroll it.

I'll be glad for any of your help I'm using react.tsx

So here are 3 pop-up's and when I click on Fullname text, my main component takes JSX.Element of Fullname component and render it as a child, after that keyboard appears and it does not move the pop-up to the top, with other's it work's fine so it happen with only first.
example:

Fullname
Email
Phone number